# Wrapping contents of element until specific element

Tags: jquery

How can I wrap in a jQuery element the contents until a specific element, as shown in this  example:

```
<div>
    <span>
       wrap this element
    </span>
    text to wrap
    <span class='dont-wrap'>
        dont wrap this
    </span>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div>
    <span>
        <span>
           wrap this element
        </span>
        text to wrap
    </span>
    <span class='dont-wrap'>
        dont wrap this
    </span>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
$('div).contents().nextUntil('.dont-wrap').wrap('<span/>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works

```
$(function(){
    $('div').contents().each(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('dont-wrap')){
            $(this).wrap('<span/>');
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9FcN3/1/)